# Is there a simpler way of repeating sequences so they have a different outcome each time?

Tags: python, random, passwords, seq

So I wrote this (scruffy) code for a password generator (bear in mind I am a beginner):

```py
import random

letter_list = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
number_list = range(0,9,1)
character_list = ["£","$","%","&","*","!","?","@"]
capital_list = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)]
random_list = [random.choice(letter_list),random.choice(number_list),random.choice(character_list),random.choice(capital_list)]

seqs = letter_list, number_list, character_list, capital_list, random_list
item = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item1 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item2 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item3 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item4 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item5 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item6 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item7 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item8 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item9 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item10 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item11 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item12 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item13 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item14 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item15 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item16 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])

print(item, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9)
```

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to write out this part, as it seems too long to be the simplest option:

```py
seqs = letter_list, number_list, character_list, capital_list, random_list
item = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item1 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item2 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item3 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item4 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item5 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item6 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item7 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item8 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item9 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item10 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item11 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item12 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item13 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item14 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item15 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
item16 = random.choice(random.choices(seqs, weights=map(len, seqs))[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the items in a list, and create one pool of characters to draw from using list concatenation.

```py
# ... [same as in original code]
# transform to list to allow for concatenation
number_list = list(str(i) for i in range(9))
# ... [same as in original code]

seqs = letter_list + number_list + character_list + capital_list + random_list
items = [random.choice(seqs) for _ in range(18)]
print(' '.join(item for item in items[:10]))
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if it would be possible to display the outcome with no spaces between characters - if I run it right now, it prints all the characters with spaces inbetween - I would usually use 
,sep='' 
but it does not seem to work in this instance.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `''.join()` rather than `' '.join()`. The string that you join on is the separator.

Comment: Thanks! I will upvote once i have enough reputation to haha